# Can not pass data from factory to controller

Tags: angularjs

I have code like this with a factory:

```
angular.module("mainApp", ["kendo.directives"])

    .factory("getFormats", function() {
        var searchStr="list&John&1&1".substr(1);
        //Here I see the searchStr
        return {
            isType: function(){
                searchStr.split('&')[0];
                //Here I see the searchStr
            },
            username: function(){
                searchStr.split('&')[1];
            },
            dateFormatIndex: function(){
                searchStr.split('&')[2];
            },
            languageIndex: function(){
                searchStr.split('&')[3];
        }
    }

})

.controller("ValidationListCtrl", function( $scope,getFormats) {
     var isType=getFormats.isType(); //Here I see the undefined
     var username=getFormats.username();//Here I see the undefined
     var dateFormatIndex=getFormats.dateFormatIndex();//Here I see the undefined
     var languageIndex=getFormats.languageIndex();//Here I see the undefined
}
```

But i get all the variables as undefined in controller. I also have checked the factory when i get it in controller and see it with empty object

```
   Object {}dateFormatIndex: (){arguments: nullcaller: nulllength: 0name: ""prototype: dateFormatIndex__proto__: Empty() {}<function scope>isType: (){languageIndex: (){username: (){__proto__: Object
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

Forgot to use return in factory methods, now it should work:)

```
angular.module("mainApp", ["kendo.directives"])

    .factory("getFormats", function() {
        var searchStr="list&John&1&1".substr(1);

        return {
         isType: function(){
               return searchStr.split('&')[0];

         },
        username: function(){
            return  searchStr.split('&')[1];
        },
        dateFormatIndex: function(){
           return   searchStr.split('&')[2];
        },
        languageIndex: function(){
          return searchStr.split('&')[3];
        }
    }

})
```

Comment: Thanks for excelent answer!

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning the values in any of the methods inside the factory. Do something like the following :

```
angular.module("mainApp", ["kendo.directives"])

    .factory("getFormats", function() {
        var searchStr="list&John&1&1".substr(1);
//Here I see the searchStr
        return {
            isType: function(){
                return searchStr.split('&')[0];
//Here I see the searchStr

},
        username: function(){
            return searchStr.split('&')[1];
        },
        dateFormatIndex: function(){
            return searchStr.split('&')[2];
        },
        languageIndex: function(){
            return searchStr.split('&')[3];
        }
    }

});
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for excelent answer!

Comment: Please close the question :) (And let me earn some points ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is you can use modular / revealing module pattern  , which helps in encapsulation as well as code readability  as below

```
  angular.module("mainApp", ["kendo.directives"])

.factory("getFormats", function() {
    var _searchStr="list&John&1&1".substr(1),

        _isType = function(){
           return _searchStr.split('&')[0];

        },

       _username =  function(){
        return  _searchStr.split('&')[1];
      }
            .....
    return {
     isType :_isType ,
     username:_username
     .....
   }

})
```

so in your controller or in another service you can get it as

```
   getFormats.username(//arguments if required)
   username.isType(//arguments if required)
```

Comment: Thanks for excelent answer!

Comment: @TuviaKhusid no problem Tuvia , happy to help :):)